# ng-options trackby in group expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

What am I doing wrong here that Angular (1.1.5) is not properly selecting the correct value in this grouped select dropdown?

HTML: `<select ng-model="options.metricId" ng-options="answer.id as answer.name group by answer.question for answer in options.answers track by answer.id"></select>`

`options.metricId` is being set properly by the controller.

The `options.answers` object looks like this: 
`{id: 8, name: "Leads Others", question: "Assessment"}`

All the options are appearing, but it is not selecting the value where `answer.id == options.metricId` as I would expect it to.

Comment: Why do you have `class=ng-model="options.metricId"`?

Comment: sorry.  was trying to remove the classes for brevity, but did not fully backspace. will fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `parseInt(answer.id)` to the track expression solved the issue.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="options.metricId" ng-options="answer.id as answer.name group by answer.question for answer in options.answers track by parseInt(answer.id)" ng-change="events.updateMetrics()"></select>
```